# Kubernetes access to port on node from inside pod?

Tags: kubernetes

I am trying to access a service listening on a port running on every node in my bare metal (Ubuntu 20.04) cluster from inside a pod. I can use the real IP address of one of the nodes and it works. However I need pods to connect to the port on their own node. I cant use '127.0.0.1' inside a pod.

More info: I am trying to wrangle a bunch of existing services into k8s. We use an old version of Consul for service discovery and have it running on every node providing DNS on 8600. I figured out how to edit the coredns Corefile to add a consul { } block so lookups for .consul work.

```
consul {
    errors
    cache 30
    forward . 157.90.123.123:8600
}
```

However I need to replace that IP address with the "address of the node the coredns pod is running on".

Any ideas? Or other ways to solve this problem? Tx.

Comment: Are you already aware of [the `fieldRef` of `status.hostIP` as an env-var](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubernetes-api/v1.21/#objectfieldselector-v1-core) (I think you can mount the downward API as a volume, too, if that's easier)?

Comment: Tx. That might work. Seems coredns will expand env vars in the Corefile: https://coredns.io/manual/configuration/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Comment from @mdaniel worked. Tx.

Edit coredns deployment. Add this to the container after volumeMounts:

```
env:
- name: K8S_NODE_IP
  valueFrom:
    fieldRef:
      fieldPath: status.hostIP
```

Edit coredns config map. Add to bottom of the Corefile:

```
consul {
    errors
    cache 30
    forward . {$K8S_NODE_IP}:8600
}
```

Check that DNS is working

```
kubectl run tmp-shell --rm -i --tty --image nicolaka/netshoot -- /bin/bash
nslookup myservice.service.consul
nslookup www.google.com
exit
```